# Navbar bootstrap dropdown not working on certain url's

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, navbar, dropdown

I using a navbar from bootstrap from Carousel Templates
And the drop down in my navbar is working but when I go to a specific URL in my website is not dropping down and is stuck on highlighted mode for some reason which I can't figure out why 
I open the console in web seeing if there is any error popping and nothing was shown, **But** when I noticed is that in the url's that it work's
when I click on the drop-down it's adding a **show** class to the  but when I click on the problematic URL I'm in it isn't adding that class which make me frustrated

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="dropdown03" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
<i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i> see more </a>
<div class="dropdown-menu bg-info" aria-labelledby="dropdown03">
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">exmple1</a>
<a class="dropdown-item glyphicon glyphicon-picture" href="#">exmple2</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">exmple3</a>
</div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check within your problem page's header to see if it has the same bootstrap as your base template's header. If they have the same bootsrap links, you may want to try deleting the problem page's bootstrap links, then re-running.

Comment: yes thanks the problem was that i had multiples headers and body tags which wasnt necessary ,

Comment: do you know maybe if there is a way to make an undo for                                python manage.py collcectstatic --nonpiont --clear???   i deleted by accident many files

Comment: Did you commit and push to github?